# WCF: An error while trying to serialize parameter of List / Array type

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I want to obtain avaible data contract types at run-time, that's why I'm using `ServiceKnownType` attribute:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownTypes", typeof(KnownTypesProvider))]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    object GetData(bool list);
}
public static class KnownTypesProvider
{
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownTypes(ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        return new[] { typeof(CompositeType) };
    }
}
```

I have no problem when returning a `CompositeType` from `GetData` method, but returning a list (`List<CompositeType>`) or an array (`CompositeType[]`) causes a serialization error:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public object GetData(bool list)
    {
        return list ?
            // serialization error
            (object)new List<CompositeType>() :
            // successfull result
            new CompositeType();
    }
}
```

Error is:

> There was an error while trying to serialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:GetData. The InnerException message was
>   'Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WcfService2.CompositeType, WcfService2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'
>   with data contract name
>   'ArrayOfCompositeType:http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService2'
>   is not expected. Add any types not known statically to the list of
>   known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute
>   or by adding them to the list of known types passed to
>   DataContractSerializer.

I thought WCF supports collection serialization by default. Am I missing something?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can return `List<CompositeType>()` instead of `object`. You don't need to use the `knowntype` in this case.

Try changing your method to

```
        public List<CompositeType> GetData1(bool list)
        {
            return new List<CompositeType>();
            // successfull result
        }
```